# get latest video Id from YouTube APIs return video id after 30 to 40 second delay

Tags: youtube-data-api

'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelId='.$channel.'&key='.$key.'&maxResults=1&order=date'

Suppose video published at 2023-04-13 02:40:00.
When I use API
'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelId='.$channel.'&key='.$key.'&maxResults=1&order=date'

When I hit this API at timestamp 2023-04-13 02:40:01

It does not return latest video ID. It returns after 30 to 40 seconds.

Comment: 30-40 secs maybe  the time taken by the server for processing the file. For every video there are dozens of formats to create...

Comment: Any other way to get latest video Id?

Comment: What do you mean for "latest"? Last uploaded?

Comment: Yes Suppose video published at 2023-04-13 02:40:00.
I need video id at  2023-04-13 02:40:00 or  2023-04-13 02:40:01

Comment: You cannot obtain a date in the past. If server takes 3 hours to put the video online, how can it return a wrong date?

Comment: Suppouse video published at 2023-04-13 02:40:00. I got notification on my mobile device at 2023-04-13 02:40:00 means server put the video online. then why we cannot obtain video id.